# Player having strange bouncing/flinging behavior in my VR game

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

I am developing a VR application using the Gorilla Tag locomotion sourced from GitHub, and I have been having this strange issue I haven't come across before, the issue is the hands seem to be kind of flinging or having a stringing bouncy like behavior. I have tested around and found it most likely does not have anything to do with strange collisions and have found that the gorilla rig seemed to work fine in a much simpler example scene I made. Please ask any questions you need!

Any help is appreciated as I have been working on this issue for days with little to no luck.

Thanks,
Cullis

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out that universal pipe line is the problem so use the built in pipe line

Comment: I actually can say that the render pipeline does not seem to be the issue. I updated unity to the latest 2021 LTS and started a new project so far its been going well without the issue.

Answer (score 0):

the issue is URP with any version of unity above 2020 I highly don't recommend using built in as performance is degraded seriously especially if your using 2021 or above if you need more help contact: Sanford PE!#9019